# Как узнать цвет пикселя в текстуре?

Tags: c++, изображения, поиск-библиотек

Есть у меня текстура в формате TGA. Зная Х и У как я могу получить цвет пикселя? Какие библиотеки для этого подключить или скачать?

Comment: Если вы ищете библиотеки, то, наверное, стоит указать язык программирования. Добавьте его метку (а также метку "поиск-библиотек") в вопрос с помощью кнопки "править"

Comment: Диффузная... странное определение. Полупрозрачная? C TGA можно вытащить массив RGB, если TGA  поддерживает полупрозрачность (не сталкивался, PNG поддерживает) - то можно вытащить массив RGBA (либо массив RGB и массив-"маску"). Если имеется ввиду "плиточность", то есть конкретные компоненты поддерживающие tile - замостить фон картинкой, для разных технологий свои. Для браузера - свои, для GDI - Brush, и т д.

Comment: Текстура типа в разверстке. Типа географической карты, из шара сделали плоскость.

Comment: А как вообще вытащитЬ RGB из любого типа изображений, прозрачностЬ не обязателЬно.

Comment: Классический вариант - `stb_image`.

Comment: Может я что-то упускаю, но как насчет [GetPixel](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getpixel)

Comment: Да. Смотрел насчет GetPixel. Какой то чувак написал что можно исполЬзоватЬ GetRValue, GetGValue или что то типа такого. Но вот не могу применитЬ для tga файла